# ASP.NET MVC5 EF6 PagedList as Partial is returning whole page BUT only sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What can be causing the following script to only fire randomly when it feels like it? i.e. if I comment in the alert(44); it pops up sometimes once at the start when I click on page 2. Then I click other pages in the pager and no alert(44) but I get the WHOLE page reloading and not just the partial

So in effect its like I have no problem but only if I can force the Javascript Click below to run all the time when the Pager bar is clicked

```
  $(function () {
        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            //alert(44);
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#ResultsList').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The Javascript above is inside  "$(document).ready(function () {" and part of my main file called index.cshtml

Also in index.cshtml I have

```
<div id="ResultsList" style="clear:both;">

    @Html.Partial("IndexSearchResults")

</div>
```

In IndexSearchResults I have :

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<AscendancyCF.Domain.Premise>



<p>
    Results <span class="badge">@string.Format("{0:n0}", ViewBag.ResultCount)</span> of <span class="badge">@string.Format("{0:n0}", ViewData["TotalRecords"])</span> Premises <div id="LoadingGif"></div>
</p>


    <table class="table" id="myTable" data-link="row">
        <thead>
            <tr>


                <th>
                    Core Spid
                </th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <a href="/SupplyPoint/Details/@item.SupplyPoints.First().SupplyPointId"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoreSPID)</a>

                    </td>


                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <div id="myPager">

        @Html.Partial("Pager")


    </div>
```

Finally Controller Code is :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NotAuthorised.cshtml");


        ViewData["TotalRecords"] = _db.FindAllPremises().Count();
        ViewData["ResultCount"] = 0;
        ViewBag.InitialPageCount = 10;

        var obj = _db.FindAllPremiseEmpty();
        return View("Index", obj.ToPagedList(1, 10));


    }

    public ActionResult IndexSearch(int? page, string searchSPID, string searchPremise, string searchPostcode, int optVacant, int OptOurSpids, string searchCompany, string searchLP)
    {
        var searchResults = getSearchResults(searchSPID, searchPremise, searchPostcode, optVacant, OptOurSpids, searchCompany, searchLP);
        ViewData["TotalRecords"] = _db.FindAllPremises().Count();
        ViewBag.ResultCount = searchResults.Count();

        ViewBag.searchSPID = searchSPID;
        ViewBag.searchPremise = searchPremise;
        ViewBag.searchPostcode = searchPostcode;
        ViewBag.optVacant = optVacant;
        ViewBag.OptOurSpids = OptOurSpids;
        ViewBag.searchCompany = searchCompany;
        ViewBag.searchLP = searchLP;

        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        if (searchResults == null)
            return View("NotFound");

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("IndexSearchResults", searchResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }


        return View("Index", searchResults.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

    }
```

I have code that gets fired from SEARCH button in index.aspx. This now only runs once and fails after I have clicked on the pager, here it is:

function performSearch() {

```
    var url = '/Premise/IndexSearch';


    var data = {
        searchSPID: $('#SearchSPID').val().toString(),
        searchPremise: $('#SearchPremise').val().toString(),
        searchPostcode: $('#SearchPostcode').val().toString(),
        optVacant: $("input[name='OptVacantOrOccupied']:checked").attr("id"),
        OptOurSpids: $("input[name='OptOurSpids']:checked").attr("id"),
        SearchCompany: $('#SearchCompany').val().toString(),
        SearchLP: $('#SearchLP').val().toString()
    };

    $("#ResultsList").load(url, data, function () {
        $('#LoadingGif').empty(); 
    });


    $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" width=31 height=31 alt="Loading image" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #myPager event handler is lost when the page is updated due to the element being removed from the dom.  If you want to do this kind of thing, always attach your dom event to a part of the page that doesn't get removed, your handlers won't get destroyed then.

Try and keep to as close to your original element as possible to stop a mass of handlers slowing down your page.

Here is an updated script:

```
$(function () {
    $('#ResultsList').on('click', '#myPager a', function (evt) {
        var target = $(evt.currentTarget);
        $.ajax({
            url: target.attr("href"),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ResultsList').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks right.

Comment: thanks, that sorted my Pager, in that I can click now and it behaves correct. But the main search button now can only be clicked once. Like the fix has impacted somehow. I have attached the Javascript that is fired on the on click of the main search button, many thanks

Comment: Its OK, a small change to my controller so it only returns partial, all good thanks